# Extending windows based installer to other Operating Systems

Tags: installation, platform-independent

I have build an installer using NSIS. And now I want to extend it to Solaris and Linux thorugh WINE. But I wanna know few things here-

1. Is WINE flavour dependent? I mean are there different packages for different Linux versions?
2. Whats if my Installer creates some SQL or Oracle database? Will this feature be also supported by WINE?
3. Is there any tool which can be used to build installer which is platform independent?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [InstallJammer](http://www.installjammer.com/) for a free, open source, cross-platform install builder that supports the platforms you need.  See if that'll do what you want. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your approach is that then you require the end-user to have Wine pre-installed. You may be better using a multiplatform installation tool like [InstallBuilder](http://installbuilder.bitrock.com)
 (disclaimer, I am the author of InstallBuilder)